# How to switch SKScenes in SpriteKit with Swift properly?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene, skview

I am developing a game with 3 different SKScenes(scene1, scene2, scene3). In GameViewController i initialize all of them like this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
  var hero = Hero()
  var skView: SKView!

  var scene1: SKScene!
  var scene2: SKScene!
  var scene3: SKScene!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // init scenes
    scene1 = SKScene(size: view.bounds.size, hero: hero)
    scene2 = SKScene(size: view.bounds.size, hero: hero)
    scene3 = SKScene(size: view.bounds.size, hero: hero)

    scene1.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    scene2.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    scene3.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    // set view
    skView = self.view as SKView

    // present the first scene
    skView.presentScene(scene1)
}
```

My idea is to present the first scene at first and present(swith to) the other scene later(i.e. when hero is stronger). In each scene the hero sprite was added like this:

```
  func addHero() {
    let heroSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hero")
    hero.sprite = heroSprite
    heroSprite.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/4, y: size.height/2)
    addChild(heroSprite)
  }
```

And in update method, hero position is updated by touching.

```
func update() {
  if touching {
    hero.position++
  }
}
```

Hero class looks like this:

```
class Hero {
  var sprite: SKSpriteNode?
}
```

**The problem is**: 
The hero is movable by touching when **only** the first scene(scene1) is initialized. Which means, the hero is not movable any more with code above.

Can anyone give me some advice what have i done wrong? Thanks in advance!

PS: The complete codes can be found in [Github](https://github.com/chensifeng/Chicken).

Comment: Can you add your update function , also you should use touches moved function to move your sprite by touching .

Comment: Yes, the update() function is very simple. I have edited the post. I am thinking what happened to the 3 scenes, when they are initialized. Are they all running at the same time or only when they are presented?

Comment: When exactly do you present your next scene , e.g : in the same function or in another function or in another class ?

Comment: @AbdullahOssamaOmari the next scene will be presented in GameViewController as well, but only when the condition is meet. After test, i find the issue is due to "addHero()" function. It is called 3 times after the 3 scenes initialization. Whereas i am still not clear, why hero is not movable. Its sprite is just added to 3 different scenes. (thinking...)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved by another related question: [Sprites must be cleaned before switch scenes with SpriteKit and Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294128/sprites-must-be-cleaned-before-switch-scenes-with-spritekit-and-swift)

By switching scenes, be sure not to add the sprites twice by checking the init status. For example in "didMoveToView", "init" or "setup" method:

```
if isInit {
  do nothing
} else {
  add sprites
  isInit = true
}
```